# List to varargs with pre-difined size or without size

Tags: java, arrays

What is the better way to convert List to varargs to call below 'builder( String... s )' method.

```
builder( stringList.toArray( new String[stringList.size()] ) );//with pre-difined array size
```

or

```
builder( stringList.toArray( new String[0] ) );//without predifined size
```

for example

```
void test() {

  List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
  builder( stringList.toArray( new String[stringList.size()] ) );//call builder method with pre-difining array size
  builder( stringList.toArray( new String[0] ) );//call builder method with array size 0

}

void builder( String... s )
{

}
```

I faced this question in a review and I was suggested that `builder( stringList.toArray( new String[0] ) )` is more efficient than 
using `builder( stringList.toArray( new String[stringList.size()] ) )`.
Is there a significant difference between these two?
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't matter. This is a micro-optimization question that will have 0 noticeable impact on the performance. Use what you find the most readable.

Comment: It depends. Both methods behave differently. The first will use the given array if it is large enough. If it's not, it is not used. So, if you use it with the correct size, the code will create one object less. Which is one object less to clean up.

Comment: One of the Oracle performance engineers did tests on this: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/#_conclusion

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger So you mean that builder method is again creating an array when we called 'new String[0]'  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To my understanding

```
stringList.toArray( new String[stringList.size()] ) )
```

is more efficient. The reason:

The argument is needed to have an actual type (`String`) for a generic `List<String>`, where the generic type parameter is erased at run-time.

The argument is used for the resulting array if its size matches the list size.

If the size is 0, the passed array is discarded.

So passing a correct array saves one object creation.

Of course `list.size()` is called extra. So it might be slower. I doubt it.

---

***Correction***

See [Arrays of Wisdom of the Ancients](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/).
A correct benchmark shows the inverse: `new String[0]` being faster.
I just overflew the very interesting analysis, and it seems:

- (an extra short lived `new String[0]` is irrelevant;)
- doing the array copying local in the toArray method allows a different, faster array copy;
- (and then there is the extra call to `size`.)

Mind, I did not sufficiently thorough read the article; it really is interesting.

Conclusion (counter-intuitively): **`new T[0]` is faster.**

Mind that:

- code checkers might still think differently and issue a warning;
- this is with warming up: till the hotspot JIT kicks in, it may be the other way around.

Comment: just the question if `list.size()` is slower than what other(?) method `toArray` uses to find out the size (probably the same, so no difference) / well, actually `toArray` will have to check the size anywawys...

Comment: toArray internally will call list.size() a second time, to check the size, and possible to create an own array. So one extra call is made. For Java SE List implementations, where the size is a counter field, the overhead is neglectable compared to `new String[0]`. But some idiotic lazy immutable linked list implementation could have no such counter maintained, needing to count every node. Absolutely unlikely though. _I think I should not have mentioned it._

Comment: @JoopEggen it's the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775139/1059372

Comment: @Eugene thanks for this very interesting link. It always is nice to be corrected on such fundamental case. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`builder(stringList.toArray(new String[0]))` is slightly **less** efficient since you create an empty array that will be discarded and never used after the method returns. `toArray` will have to create a new array in order to store the elements of the `List`.

On the other hand, `builder(stringList.toArray(new String[stringList.size()]))` passes an array of the required length to the `toArray` method, and therefore that method will use that array instead of creating a new array.

Comment: well, unless you measure this is called guessing and some people proved that it's the other way around https://stackoverflow.com/a/51775139/1059372

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference and it's mainly outlined [by the Alexey Shipilev](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/). Long story short:

> toArray(new T[0]) seems faster, safer, and contractually cleaner, and therefore should be the default choice now

Answer (score 1):

I thought that `c.toArray(new String[c.size()]))` is more efficient, because we define here an array with required size.

**BUT!!**

*IntelliJ IDEA* has **Collection.toArray()** inspection, which is on by default. This is description:

> There are two styles to convert a collection to an array: either using
>   a pre-sized array (like **c.toArray(new String[c.size()]))** or using an
>   empty array (like **c.toArray(new String[0])**.
>
> In older Java versions
>   using pre-sized array was recommended, as the reflection call which is
>   necessary to create an array of proper size was quite slow. However
>   since late updates of OpenJDK 6 this call was intrinsified, making the
>   performance of the empty array version the same and sometimes even
>   better, compared to the pre-sized version. Also passing pre-sized
>   array is dangerous for a concurrent or synchronized collection as a
>   data race is possible between the size and toArray call which may
>   result in extra nulls at the end of the array, if the collection was
>   concurrently shrunk during the operation.
>
> This inspection allows to follow the uniform style: either using an
>   empty array (which is recommended in modern Java) or using a pre-sized
>   array (which might be faster in older Java versions or non-HotSpot
>   based JVMs).

So it seems, that after JDK6, we should use `c.toArray(new String[0])`. My personal opinion, is that **it doesn't matter what aporoach to use this time**. Only if profiler says that this is a bottle neck, then we should worry about it.

Comment: profilers and professionals have already tested this: https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/