# pick first N elements from a static list java

Tags: java, arrays

I want to pick first N elements from a list in java

```
String[] ligature = new String{there,is not,a,single,person,who,knows,the,answer};
```

Now I want to pick first 5 elements from this.something like

`Stiring[] selectedLigature = ligature[0:4];`

I want to do it without using for loop.

Comment: Why? Better use `List`. You could do: `Arrays.asList(ligature).subList( 0,5 ).toArray()`; But that is cumbersome.

Comment: @RobAu `.toArray(new String[5])` would be needed if one wants to get a typed array back

Comment: @Lino that  is silly. You just need `toArray(new String[0])` as the argument  is only used to determine the type.

Comment: @RobAu if the length of the input array is equal or bigger than the `List` then it is used. At least in the case of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @Lino. Didn't know! It also sets elements in given array to `null` if it is bigger. Thanks!

Comment: @Lino is should *always* be `new String[0]` without an actual size https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51766615/list-to-varargs-with-pre-difined-size-or-without-size/51775139#51775139

Answer (score 10):

Do *not* stream this simple case, there is `subList` for this:

```
// for a List
yourList.subList(0, 5)...

// for an array
Arrays.copyOfRange
```

Comment: Agreed. `subList` is almost always better, but tricky as you can modify the original list by accident as it is just a view on the `List`.

Comment: @RobAu `Arrays.copyOfRange` for such a case

Comment: @Eugene `Collections.unmodifiableList` will return an list that cannot be modified. Arrays.copyOfRange will also not deep-copy the elements inside?

Comment: @RobAu you right, me wrong, `System.arrayCopy` does not do a deep copy.

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays` class has a [method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-) for this:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(ligature, 0, 5);
```